# Positioning of divs off in Firefox/Camino?

Tags: css, firefox, html, position, camino

So, I have written out a site in HTML and CSS, and all looked fine and dandy in Safari, Chrome, OmniWeb... even Opera. Then I tested in Firefox and Camino (which I believe uses the same rendering engine as Firefox) and was unpleasantly surprised: some of the positioning of my divs was off - noticeably off - by at least 5 pixels. While that might not seem like a whole lot, I use divs to put borders around things that I would otherwise have difficulty with putting borders around (jquery image gallery, for example), so 5 pixels matters quite a bit.

My question is this - what other quirks does Firefox's rendering engine put in, and how can I get around them? Are there special properties I need to add to my CSS in order to make it behave the same for Firefox/Camino?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you set your margin and padding to zero on every element with a universal selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using a css reset, this will give you a blank slate and will for the most part normalize how browsers render the box model.

I recommend http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Comment: Ah, thanks, that seemed to do the trick. I'll have to re-position some elements in my design, but at least it's consistent across browsers. :)